# Distinguish HLS content during stream

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to distinguish the content type of data incoming from a HLS stream using Google's ExoPlayer.

Specifically, I want to distinguish between Video and Audio-only content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Accoridng to the Exoplayer documentation the player does not currently support detecting the media format at all:

> ExoPlayer does not (yet) automatically detect the format of the media being played. An application needs to know the format of the media it wishes to play in order to construct an ExoPlayer capable of playing it. Removing this limitation is tracked by Issue #438.

The issue link mentioned above is: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/438

You could look at the raw stream yourself if you can access it (it is not encrypted) and figure out from there if it is audio or video but this will need a reasonable amount of work: HLS is a 'streaming protocol' that streams MPEG-2 transport streams, chunked into segments. Each of these MPEG-2 transport streams can contain audio and video.

The MPEG standards (MPEG 1 and MPEG 2) use stream ids to identify each individual audio or video stream in the transport stream. Audio streams are numbered 110X XXXX and video streams 1110XXXX - hence you can check all the individual streams in an MPEG2 transport stream and see if whether it is audio only, video only or a mix.

Comment: nice quote. Nicer solution suggestion. Can you please edit your answer with a snippet to testing the MPEG-2 transport stream for containing audio/video/both? Thanks

Comment: Added some more detail on how you can check for audio and video streams - sorry don't have any code to give you! This will be a reasonable amount of work - it might be worth experimenting with the player and seeing if there is some easier trick you can use to meet your needs, for example seeing if an error is generated if you try to play a video for a HLS stream which has no video and then simply catch the error and assume the stream is audio only.

Comment: I will try it out and update with code snippets - you can then add them to your answer and I'll pick it - thanks!!